# Assign an incoherent range to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to get an incoherent range assigned to a variable but I just can't seem to get it right. Can anyone please help me?

My code looks like this:

```
    Dim tstRange As Range
    Dim strRange As String
    Select Case strSite
        Case "Lerum/Aspedalen"
            strRange = "B" & iLastRow & ", H" & iLastRow & ":L" & iLastRow
            With Kurtans_favorit
                Set tstRange = .Range(strRange)
                Set tstRange = .Range("B" & iLastRow, "H" & iLastRow & ":L" & iLastRow)
            End With
```

Neither the first nor the second way to assign the range to `tstRange` works (well, actually the first one does, but it is only giving me the content of the first cell in the range, which is not my intention).

I intend to use this range to check if they contain any values. If they do the user will get a question whether to overwrite or cancel the operation he/she is doing.

Comment: Your first one is correct, so I assume that it's however you are trying to *use* that range that is actually the problem.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify?
I don't understand your comment.

Comment: You said the first one worked "but it is only giving me the content of the first cell in the range". That is not the case so I assume it's however you were checking the values that is the problem. If you check `tstRange.Cells.Count` is the result correct - i.e. 5?

Comment: Actually it gives me the result of 6, which is correct. The second one gives me 11 and is a little bit confusing.

Comment: Alternative is `Set tstRange = .Range("B1,H1:L1").Offset(iLastRow-1)`

Comment: Thanks Rory,
I will go for the first version. It does work. I need to ad quite a lot of ranges into one incoherent range so this was just the first try.
I don't understand why the second doesn't work but I settle for the first one using a string to create the range/ranges.
Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: Thanks CDP1802. 
That looks like a great solution. 
Seems to be the least bit of coding and very clear and readable solution.

Comment: If you supply two arguments to Range, the result is everything from the top left cell of the first range to the bottom right cell of the second range, including all cells in between. You'd need `Union` if you don't want to just concatenate the range address string.

Comment: Another alternative: `Set tstRange = Intersect(.Range("B:B,H:L"), .Rows(iLastRow))`. Keep in mind that Intersect is slow and is best avoided when possible. To conclude, CDP1802's suggestion is superior (more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OlaJohnson()

    PrintAllRangeMembers RangeString:="A1,C1:E1"

End Sub

Private Sub PrintAllRangeMembers(RangeString As String)

    ' Purpose:
    ' Iterate through all members of a range and print them to the Immediate window

    Dim IncoRange As Range
    Set IncoRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(RangeString)
    
    Dim Cell As Variant
    For Each Cell In IncoRange
        Debug.Print Cell
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

The `Sub PrintAllRangeMembers` takes a `Range` (coherent or not) as an argument, iterates through all members via a `For Each` loop, and prints the values to the Immediate window.

You can perform whatever checks you need to make in the `For Each` loop.  Printing the values of the cells was just to demonstrate that the expected behaviour results.